# Typeset single chapter from book

Tags: compiling

I am working on a multi-chaptered document, tied together with a main tex file that pulls the chapters in via \include. To build the entire document, in its current draft form, can take upwards of 15-20 minutes, depending on the machine I am working on. I am wondering if there is a way that I could choose to typeset only one  specific chapter at a time without having to restructure my whole setup. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `\includeonly` in the preamble. Done!

Comment: 15-20 minutes!? That seems like an awfully long time. What's in this book?

Comment: Hah, about 7 gazillion figures. It seems to bog down most when I include the image-heavy chapters.

Comment: @mrdillion: you do not need to insert all the figures every time! If only text chnages are important use `draft` as optional argument for the documentclass or alternatively as option for `\includegraphics` for single big images and change it in a final run to `final` or simply delete the draft option.

Comment: I'd say it's a duplicate of [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3462/1235), but the title of that question is not really helpful ...

Comment: @Seamus: The Metafun manual used to take 10-15 minutes to compile with pdftex. But most of the time was spent in generating metapost figures. With luatex, it takes around 3 minutes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using `\include` for your chapters, then you can use `\includeonly` to include just specific chapters.

e.g.

```
\documentclass{book}
\includeonly{Chap2} % will cause just Chap 2 to be included
\begin{document}
\include{Chap1}
\include{Chap2}
\include{Chap3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: or altenatively also `\excludeonly` which needs the package of the same name.

Answer (score 5):

Include all chapters in the **body** using `\include` macro (to make cross references work properly) and specify the chapter to be rendered using `\includeonly` in the **preamble**.

Cross references will still work properly even thought you just render only one chapter.

```
\documentclass{book}
\includeonly{ch01}
\begin{document}
\include{ch01}
\include{ch02}
\include{ch03}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to run at least one time _all_ chapters to create the auxiliary files.