# Creating multiple PDF files from a single LaTeX file

Tags: compiling, chapters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create individual chapter PDFs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31334/how-to-create-individual-chapter-pdfs)

In my LaTeX file, I have

```
\chapter{chapter one}

\chapter{chapter two}

\chapter{chapter three}
```

etc.

I wonder if there is a way to create separate PDF files for each chapter, i.e. `chapter one.pdf`, `chapter two.pdf`, `chapter three.pdf` etc.  As there are quite a few chapters in my document and they keep changing, separating the chapters manually can prove to be time consuming and ineffective. I am using texlive in Ubuntu.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, see [Typeset single chapter from book](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8400/typeset-single-chapter-from-book). Put every chapter in its own file and use `\include{<file>}` in the main file. Then add `\includeonly{<files/chapter you want include>}` in the preamble. You need to change this line for every chapter and compile the document again, then rename the PDF. However, I don't know an automatic way. You could write a shell script which automates it for you, if you know how to do it.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31334/how-to-create-individual-chapter-pdfs/31362#31362