# Possibility to decrease the compilation time

Tags: speed

In my document, I'm having many 4 color (CMYK) images and photos in EPS format (nearly 50 images), I'm using `LaTeX-dvips-PS2PDF`, the compilation takes more time, is there any possibility to speed up the compilation process? Need your suggestions

Comment: There are some options, but they all boil down to "don't compile your full document so often". For example: switch off all images with `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}` or `[demo]` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51893), compile only your current chapter (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8400), use lower quality image files and replace them with the originals on the final camera-ready run. And in general uou can write longer and compile maybe every hour or so, possibly keeping a small sandbox document on the side to try out things like table layout or formulas.

Comment: Note that for EPS images you don't need to use dvips-ps2pdf anymore, since somewhere around 2010 pdfLaTeX is able to include EPS images by converting them on the fly to pdf (which is technically and quality-wise equivalent to what ps2pdf does). So you can just do `\includegraphics{your-eps-image}`, compile with pdflatex, and get the image included in the final pdf output of the document (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38528/) for example).

Comment: You can also use a graphics editor or standalone to create a permanent pdf version of the eps image.

Comment: Thanks to all, will check with your suggestions and get back

Comment: @Marijn Actually, I need to do PDF with some Specific printer option like `Sheridan`, so only I'm using `dvips` and using `Acrobat Distiller` with job option as `Sheridan`, is it possible to implement the `Printer` setting by using `PDFLaTeX` ? Please advise.

Comment: @GowriSaro from what I can tell the Sheridan settings in Distiller are some general options on how to handle images, fonts, gradients etc. These settings can be influenced from code using things like `\pdfcatalog`, the [pdfmanagement](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfmanagement-testphase) package, hyperref options etc. However, if you are happy with your current Distiller workflow then I would not change that, I just mentioned the EPS issue because often people think that pdflatex cannot handle EPS while it works fine with the automatic internal conversion.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks, I will check the suggested packages