# Using \import correctly

Tags: external-files, import

I've got a main-file which includes the preamble. I then use `\import` to put together all chapters of my final document. When saving the main-file in another directory than the chapter-files I get the message:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `GDP.tex' not found.
```

Isn't the idea of `\import` to import files from different directories? Is there maybe something wrong with my code?

```
...    
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\import{/Users/john/Documents/Uni/Studienarbeit/Latex/Kapitel/GDP}{Methodology}
\import{/Users/john/Documents/Uni/Studienarbeit/Latex/Kapitel/GDP}{GDP}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you might be looking for `\input{/Users/john/Documents/Uni/Studienarbeit/Latex/Kapitel/GDP/Methodology}`. That is, `\input` rather than `\import`.

Comment: What package are you using that provides an `\import` command? Usually files are included with `\include` (or sometimes `\input`).

Comment: Is `Methodology.tex` found? Is both files placed in `/Users/john/Documents/Uni/Studienarbeit/Latex/Kapitel/GDP`? If you are not using `\input`(or like) in the files, then you should just use `\include` in your main file.

Comment: @Werner: When it is in the main file, `\include` is preferred over `\input`.

Comment: I will try it with \include.

@Alan Munn: I used \usepackage{import}.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen: That's a bit categorical. I prefer \input, unless I actually need \include's additional baggage and \clearpages.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: Yes - I should probably have written "I prefer ...". But I also believe that `\include` suits the purpose best here.

Comment: Absolute paths within source files are best avoided. They are bad form, since if you move your thesis to a new folder, it will no longer compile.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

When using the [`import`](http://ctan.org/pkg/import) package (which provides the `\import` command), you must ensure that the path argument includes the trailing slash `/`.  So you need to do:

```
\import{/Users/john/Documents/Uni/Studienarbeit/Latex/Kapitel/GDP/}{GDP}
```

Note the `/` at the end of the path.

**Update 2020**  As of v6.2 (part of TL 2020) the trailing slash is no longer required.

As others have noted in the comments, it's usually better to use the `\include` command for this kind of thing, although the `import` package does have some interesting capabilities for relative names within the included documents.  See [Keep chapter number of chapters inserted with \include](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3462/2693) for an example.

Comment: Because of this confusion, import.sty was updated to work when the trailing "/" is omitted.

Answer (score 64):

I know of three ways to put one `.tex` file into an other:

```
1. \include{⟨filename⟩}
2. \input{⟨filename⟩}
3. \import{⟨path⟩}{⟨filename⟩}
```

1. `\include` is only used in the main document, and is the preferred way in large documents. You can not use `\include` in documents that has themselves been included with `\include`. `\include` will always start on a new page. With `\includeonly{⟨filename1⟩,⟨filename2⟩,...}` you can tell the main document to only include some documents, for testing purpose. E.g. if you are working on `chapter7.tex` in your huge book, and want to see the compiled result, without compiling everything, then just place `\includeonly{chapter7}` in the preamble of your main document. `⟨filename⟩` needs to be a `.tex` file. Type either just the name of the file, a relative path, or a full path, but do not use the `.tex` extension.
2. `\input` is used in subdocuments, to input e.g. figures. It can also be used directly in the main document for smaller documents. Works exactly as if the contend of the file was written at the point of `\input`. Here `⟨filename⟩` can have any extension, but if none is written, then `.tex` is chosen.
3. `\import` needs the `\usepackage{import}`, and is only used, when the imported files needs the path to e.g. `\input` other files. - see the [import manual](http://ctan.org/pkg/import). Here `⟨path⟩` needs to end with a "/".

Comment: I tried it with \include but since the argument cannot be a path the include-approach does not fit to my problem. But thank you for the detailed information! :)

Comment: @John: `⟨filename⟩` can be both a filename(name), a relative path(dir/name) or a full path(/dir/name)

Comment: Okay, I did not know that, sorry. I'll keep that in mind but for the moment \import works. Thanks. :)

Comment: @John: You are welcome - plz up-vote. One approach is `if it is working, don't touch it`, but I like `Do it right from the start` better.

Comment: Great summary of the various approaches. Thanks! Upvoted.

Comment: What if I want to include code in the main document but without a new page e.g. the code for a figure? According to the explanation here, (1) won't do what I want (don't want new page), (2) is out (not a subdocument), and (3) sounds possible but unnecessary (don't need those features). In *this* kind of case, isn't (2) preferred? It works fine in main documents. I use it to include code for figures which I use in multiple documents and don't want to maintain multiple identical versions of. `\include` is wrong in that case and `\import` just adds unnecessary complexity. Am I missing something?

Comment: @cfr: I have made some edits. `\input` is indeed the correct solution.

Comment: How do I import an external .bib file into my project?

Comment: @shailenTJ: I think that it is unrelated to this answer. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management

Answer (score 5):

Note that using relative paths is in general better if you want to compile later on a different system or from a different path:

```
\import{Kapitel/GDP/}{GDP}
```

instead of

```
\import{/Users/john/Documents/Uni/Studienarbeit/Latex/Kapitel/GDP/}{GDP}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, nice user name :-)

Comment: To use a relative path as you say, one should use `\subimport` instead of `\import`. Use of `\import` with absolute paths will works sometimes but start to fail if the imported files also use import.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put this in your preamble(or second package):
`\usepackage{import}`. Then you can import as many files as you like.

Here's the full document template:

```
\documentclass[…]{…}
…
\usepackage{import}
…
\begin{document}
…
\import{path}{file.ext}
…
\end{document}
```

`path` can be of the form `./folder1/…/`, `/folder1/…/`, or an absolute path.

Comment: Please, can you explain with the details your solution with a screenshot?

Comment: I'm not sure how to take a screenshot.

Comment: Here's more code:  ...\usepackage{import}...\begin{document}...\import{...}{...}...\end{document}

Comment: Also, use relative positioning.

Comment: A ... means it doesn't matter what goes there, as long as it's correct.

Comment: My suggestion and to have a general MWE with specific details on your solution. My it not a critique.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: The code actually looks more like this: `...\usepackage{import}...\begin{document}...\import{...}{...}...\end{document}`

Comment: Using the { } icon-button when you write a question or an answer.

Comment: I know how to automatically do it. However, for some time, I didn't know it also worked for comments. Also, I don't have a button for code in the comment area.