# Usage of \include, \input and \import commands

Tags: import

hpekristiansen answer from [Using \import correctly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44480/using-import-correctly) There are three ways to put subfile.tex file into main.tex:

1. `\include{⟨filename⟩}`
2. `\input{⟨filename⟩}`
3. `\import{⟨path⟩}{⟨filename⟩}`

It is clear that

- `\include` is only used in the `main.tex` and `\include` can not be used in `subfile.tex`
- `\input` can be used in `main.tex` or `subfile.tex`
- `\import` needs `\usepackage{import}`.

Now I'm confused about using `\import`. When this should be used? 
What is the use of `\subimport`?

The point is that there is no example in the manual for `import`. I have different files in different folders. How to use `\import` with giving the path of `subfile.tex`?

Should I use `\input` for importing TikZ pictures using a standalone file `subfile.tex`?

Comment: In short, you need to use `\import` (absolute paths) or `\subimport` (relative paths) if you want to nest imports, and want the imported file (first level) to use its own path as the base for further imports (second level). If your TikZ picture doesn't make further imports, you don't need to use `\import`. I've recently posted [an example](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58485/14697), let me know whether or not it's sufficiently clear (there's room for improvement, I guess).

Comment: @dgs \input: inverse search is not possible in YAP when the input file is in subfloders. But using \import it is possible.

Comment: @dgs, your comment seems to answer this question. Please [post it as such](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/what-if-a-comment-answers-a-question), maybe with a little more explanation, so that it can be accepted.

Answer (score 7):

When you use the `import` package (which provides the `\import` command), you must use slashes `/` in your path.

E.g.

```
\import{/Users/Public/Documents/}{subfile}
```

Also, be sure that you put `/` at the end of the path.