# How to add \part only to TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, page-numbering, parts

I wonder how I can add a `\part` entry to the TOC without any output in the the document itself. I actually got a nearly working version:

```
\begin{filecontents}{chap1.tex}
\chapter{Chapter} This is a chapter.
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{chap2.tex}
\chapter{Chapter} This is a chapter.
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xparse,hyperref}

\NewDocumentCommand{\TOCpart}{s m}{%
   \clearpage
   \refstepcounter{part}%
   \phantomsection
   \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{%
      \IfBooleanF{#1}{\protect\numberline{\thepart}}%
      #2%
   }%
   \cleardoublepage
   \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Normal Part}
\include{chap1}

\TOCpart{TOC Part}
\include{chap2}

\part{Normal Part}
\chapter{Chapter} This is a chapter.

\TOCpart{TOC Part}
\chapter{Chapter} This is a chapter.
\end{document}
```

This works except that “II. TOC Part” should be listed with page 7 instead of 6. I.e. with the same one as the following chapter. If I change the definition to

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\TOCpart}{s m}{%
   \cleardoublepage
   \refstepcounter{part}%
   \phantomsection
   \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{%
      \IfBooleanF{#1}{\protect\numberline{\thepart}}%
      #2%
   }%
%   \cleardoublepage
   \ignorespaces
}
```

The entry has the right page number but if followed by an `\include` it appears behind the chapter entry, which is pretty wrong … so how can I combine the two definitions to get the part before the chapter but with the chapter’s page number, while still using `\include` and *don’t* moving `\TOCpart` inside of the included file?

Comment: I have a vague recollection that this sort of behaviour also occurs with Appendices and `\include`.

Comment: i haven't tried this, but i know that if an `\addcontentsline` is in the "main" file, just before an `\include`, it is deferred.  the `\addcontents` (and therefore the `\TOCpart` here) needs to go inside that `\include`d file; leave a comment in the main file saying you've done that.

Comment: You could also try to lie to `\addcontentsline` about the page it is used on: `\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\TOCpart}{s m}{%
   \clearpage
   \refstepcounter{part}%
   \phantomsection
\ifodd\c@page%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{%
      \IfBooleanF{#1}{\protect\numberline{\thepart}}%
      #2%
   }%
\else%
\addtocounter{page}{+1}%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{%
      \IfBooleanF{#1}{\protect\numberline{\thepart}}%
      #2%
   }%
\addtocounter{page}{-1}%
\fi%
   \cleardoublepage
   \ignorespaces
}
\makeatother`. If Barbara Beeton's solution works, I would recommend to use that one.

Comment: There should have been line-breaks after the "%" in the code in my preceding comment, but in comments those are just removed.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: OK. Thanks, thats what I thought … I’d prefer to not have the Parts inside the chapter includes since they belong to a higher levee, but if I think it’s the easiest way to go …

Comment: @Stephen: Thanks, that’s kind of cheating and works in this case but will fail if chapters can start on any page (which is not the case for my current project). You could make your comment into an answer for the record, since it will be much more legible …

Comment: @barbarabeeton: If you like make an answer of your comment and I’ll accept it, since your _no, it is impossible_ seems to be the correct answer to my question – unfortunately …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if an `\addcontentsline` is in the "main" file, just before an `\include`, it is deferred.

the `\addcontents` (and therefore the `\TOCpart` here) needs to go inside that `\include`d file, even though that seems counter-intuitive, and obscures the
fact that you needed to accomplish the change that way.

i recommend leaving a comment in the main file to say what you've done,
so that if you want to change the location of the "part" entry (or,
alternatively, later wonder where it's coming from), you will have an
obvious clue.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the aux file you will see that `\@input{chap2.aux}` occurs before `\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {part}{\numberline {II}TOC Part}{7}{part.2}}` and there is nothing one can do about it.  I even tried modifying `\@docinclude` to not use `\immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\@input{#1.aux}}`.

Anyway, the main key is to use `\input` instead of `\include`.  The practical difference is that `\include` forces a `\clearpage` before and after, which is redundant here.  See also [Usage of \include, \input and \import commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59545/usage-of-include-input-and-import-commands).

I also replaced `\phantomsection` to make the aux files entries for `\part` and `\TOCpart' closer in form.

```
\begin{filecontents}{chap1.tex}
\chapter{Chapter} This is a chapter.
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{chap2.tex}
\chapter{Chapter} This is a chapter.
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xparse,hyperref}

\NewDocumentCommand{\TOCpart}{s m}{%
   \cleardoublepage
   \refstepcounter{part}%
   \hypertarget{part.\arabic{part}}{\relax}%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{%
      \IfBooleanF{#1}{\protect\numberline{\thepart}}%
      #2%
   }%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Normal Part}
\input{chap1}

\TOCpart{TOC Part}
\input{chap2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks … but for a big project `\include` is much better since then I can use `\includeonly` …

Answer (score 1):

If you're always including a `\TOCpart` immediately before a `\chapter` (with no content discussion), you can use "page + 1" as the page for the `\TOCpart`. Additionally, as hyperlink jump, you can use whatever will be set by the subsequent `\chapter`. It has the form `chapter.#`.

The above is implemented below:

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents}{chap1.tex}
\chapter{Chapter} This is a chapter.
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{chap2.tex}
\chapter{Chapter} This is a chapter.
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xparse,hyperref}

\NewDocumentCommand{\TOCpart}{s m}{%
  \clearpage
  \stepcounter{part}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\contentsline{part}% type
      {\protect\numberline{\thepart} #2}% number + title
      {\number\numexpr\value{page}+1}% page number
      {chapter.\number\numexpr\value{chapter}+1}}% hyperref link
  \cleardoublepage
  \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Normal Part}
\include{chap1}

\TOCpart{TOC Part}
\include{chap2}

\part{Normal Part}
\chapter{Chapter} This is a chapter.
\chapter{Another chapter} This is a chapter.

\TOCpart{TOC Part}
\chapter{Chapter} This is a chapter.
\end{document}
```

Comment: It may be better to perform a `\cleardoublepage` before inserting the part ToC entry. Regardless, if the insertion is consistent, the above principle should work.

Answer (score 1):

> "that’s kind of cheating and works in this case but will fail if
>   chapters can start on any page (which is not the case for my current
>   project). You could make your comment into an answer for the record,
>   since it will be much more legible" ([Tobi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4918/tobi) [Sep 1 at 21:24](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264233/how-to-add-part-only-to-toc?noredirect=1#comment634214_264233))

There should have been line-breaks in the code in my comment, but in comments those are just removed. - Thus, just for the record and readability, another (*not recommended* ) way to do it:

You can try to lie (!) to `\addcontentsline` about the page it is used on:

```
\makeatletter%
\NewDocumentCommand{\TOCpart}{s m}{%
  \clearpage%
  \refstepcounter{part}%
  \phantomsection%
  \ifodd\c@page%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{%
      \IfBooleanF{#1}{\protect\numberline{\thepart}}%
      #2%
     }%
  \else%
    \addtocounter{page}{+1}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{%
      \IfBooleanF{#1}{\protect\numberline{\thepart}}%
      #2%
     }%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
  \fi%
  \cleardoublepage%
  \ignorespaces%
 }%
\makeatother%
```