# Citations for imported parts don't follow unsrtnat

Tags: bibtex, import

I have the following problem with unsrtnat not following the order of appearance in the document (sort of):

The document is split in several sub-documents. 
In the main part, a usual .bib file is included as well as citations.

In between a number of sub-documents are included using \import; each has their own share of citations that are added to the main bibliography using

```
\AtEndEnvironment{thebibliography}{
\bibitem{example}
....
}
```

The result is, if the main document is structured like

```
A(main)
B(included)
C(main)
```

That citations are numbered in the order of appearance following ACB instead of ABC.

Any suggestions?

Edit: Minimal working example, main file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\begin{document}

Example\cite{A}.
\input{sub}
Example\cite{C}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{A}
This should be the first.
\bibitem{C}
This should be the third.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

And sub-file:

```
Example\cite{B}.
\AtEndEnvironment{thebibliography}{
\bibitem{B}
This should be the second.
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: May I enquire why you are using `\import`? I never used that command, and do not know if it may be responsible for the problem. Can you use `\input` or `\include` instead, and does the problem persist in that case? Compare [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59545/usage-of-include-input-and-import-commands).

Comment: why are you adding to the bibliography like that rather than let bibtex just handle all the `\cite` as normal?

Comment: Thanks for first round of feedback. Problem persists with with input and include; above is a minimal working example.

I want to include the citations that way because the main file uses a .bib file and the sub-file is an older part that has just a bunch of bib-entries directly written in the document. Alternative approaches are also welcome :)

Comment: I agree with @DavidCarlisle, the `\AtEndEnvironment` may cause the problem. And I do not see a reason why it should be neccessary. A simple `\cite{B}` in the sub-file should suffice.

Comment: I would either just edit the included file to use `\cite` with bibtex or simply stop using bibtex at all now, and take the generated bbl file for your main file , edit in the entries from your include at whatever point you want.  Doing half by bibtex and half manually just seems to be making work.

Comment: Why do you use the `thebibliography` environment at all, instead of a simple `\bibliography{lit.bib}`?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}

Example\cite{A}.
\input{sub}
Example\cite{C}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{Lit} %name of your .bib file
\end{document}
```

With sub-file

```
Example\cite{B}.
```

Does that somehow not produce what you want/expect?

Also note, that you call `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` twice!