# Latex adds 'end.tex' to my file names. Why?

Tags: import

I have been using this code without problems and then out of the blue, it started throwing a new error.

```
% Table generated by "H:\do files\weekly_comparison_by_year.do"
\begin{table}
 \begin{tabular}{centering}
 \import{H:graphs/"table_ed_los_2019_2021.tex"}
 %\import{table_ed_los_2019_to2021.tex}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

leads to this error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `H:graphs/table_ed_los_2019_2021.tex/end.tex' not found.Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: tex)Enter file name:! Emergency stop.<read > \end
```

It appears that LaTeX is adding `/end.tex` to my file names and I cannot see why.

Comment: Look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44480/using-import-correctly)

Comment: sorry but I doubt very much that `\begin{tabular}{centering}`  could ever have worked. So don't show code that you made up, show a real, complete example and its log-file.

Comment: beside this: \import needs two arguments. As you are providing only one, it is picking up the \end from \end{tabular}.

Comment: but as you are providig the full path you could simpy use `\input` (you could use `\input` in any case.