# Splitting a big document into several output PDF files

Tags: pdf, input, include

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keep chapter number of chapters inserted with \include](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3462/keep-chapter-number-of-chapters-inserted-with-include)
>   [Can one TeX file output to multiple PDF files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/can-one-tex-file-output-to-multiple-pdf-files)

My document structure has:

- 1 file with preface;
- 12 individual `.tex` files representing chapters

Each chapter has lots of figures (2D and 3D) so each `.pdf` has about 250Mb.

Using the `\include` command I was able (more or less) to manage the compilation step, but for the final print step I'd like to have multiple `.pdf`, not a single huge `.pdf`.

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: "For the final print step" seems like you're okay with a single (huge) PDF, and you're willing to undergo some post-production to split out separate PDFs. For this, the [PDF toolkit](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) is ideal. Not sure whether this is a duplicate of the linked post.

Comment: See also [Can one TeX file output to multiple PDF files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/can-one-tex-file-output-to-multiple-pdf-files)

Comment: @MartinSchröder: ... *that* seems more like the duplicate.