# Is it possible to generate two PDF files from a single run?

Tags: parameters

The `letter` class makes it possible to generate two letters from a single run.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{letter}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\name{John Doe}
\signature{John Doe}

\begin{letter}{Mr.\ Foo Bar}
\opening{Dear Mr.\ Bar}
\lipsum[1]
\end{letter}

\begin{letter}{Mr.\ Bar Foo}
\opening{Dear Mr.\ Foo}
\lipsum[2]
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

But the resulting two letters are only logically distinct. They are generated in the same PDF file.

Is it ever possible, using any mechanism (irrelevant of `letter`), to get LaTeX to generate two ("physical", not logical) PDF files from a single run? Presumably the initialization in the preamble will be available for both.

My hunch is that this is not possible, and the best might be to concoct a shell script that [passes a (boolean) parameter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1492/9549). Can you confirm?

Comment: Why should you generate two PDF from the same LaTeX file in a single run?

Comment: It depends what you define as a 'run'. If the compilation can spawn another compilation, it can compile a second PDF. This is how the externalisation of images works in PGF/Ti*k*Z, for example. But there is a separate compilation run for each PDF. Or you can use something like `arara` or `rubber` or `mklatex` to initiate multiple compilations. Or you can 'burst' a PDF after compilation using one of those tools to automate it.

Comment: @Astrinus Why not? Otherwise, you have to split the PDF if you want to send the letters electronically, for example.

Comment: it's here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45563/splitting-a-big-document-into-several-output-pdf-files or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74243/automatically-create-two-pdf-output-files-from-one-tex-file or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/can-one-tex-file-output-to-multiple-pdf-files

Comment: @cfr you are talking about different letters, don't you? Why different documents should not go each in their own file??

Comment: @Astrinus If you are merging data into a standard template, this would be tiresome. Suppose you need to send 50 similar letters with only minor variations ...

Comment: @cfr one of the linked answers targets exactly this case. And it produces one PDF per run.

Comment: @Astrinus So? Sorry, bit confused ...