# Compiling Master and Individual Child documents with correct pagination

Tags: page-numbering, include, document-configuration

I'm using a master document by including the child documents with `\include{}` command. I can compile the master document to get the big document with all child documents included. I wonder how to get one big master document as well as individual child documents with the correct pagination through only one compile.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking exactly. Is this about saving one run of pdflatex? Or about `\includeonly` to include only parts but get the page numbers right?

Comment: Have a look at [Keep chapter number of chapters inserted with \include](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3462/2975) which also takes care about page numbers. You need to recompile the document and set the chapter you want with `\includeonly`. There is no automated process yet, but just last week when I submitted my thesis I thought about writing a package for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just one compile (not multiple compiles with `\includeonly` for one child at a time) consider extracting from the full pdf. One of these might work for you: 
http://www.bloovis.com/wordpress/?p=241, 
http://www.angusj.com/pdftkb/#pdftkbuilder,
http://multivalent.sourceforge.net/Tools/pdf/Split.html