# Export only table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, pdf, include

What would be the preferred way to export the `Table of contents` I use in a `.tex` file to a separate `.pdf`?

Currently I have a `my-report.tex` file and I wish to pair the result of `pdflatex` (`my-report.pdf`) with `my-report-toc.pdf`, which contains only the table of contents.

**Is there a simple way to achieve this?**

---

My `.tex` file has this kind of layout (simplified):

```
...
\begin{titlepage}
\includepdf[pages=-]{abstract.pdf}
\end{titlepage}

% -------------------------------------------------    
% This should go to a separate .pdf file on export.
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak
% -------------------------------------------------

\section{Section1}
...
\section{Section2}
...
\section{Section3}
...
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### PDF extraction

External tools can be used to extract pages from the PDF file, e.g. `pdftk`.
If the table of contents is on pages 5 and 6:

```
pdftk myreport.pdf cat 5-6 output myreport-toc.pdf
```

### `\include`

If the main document is separated in several `\include` files, then the
`\tableofcontents` goes into a separate file `myreport-tableofcontents.tex`:

```
\tableofcontents
\newpage
```

and in `myreport.tex` to include its toc:

```
\include{myreport-tableofcontents}
```

Then `myreport-toc.tex` only includes the table of contents:

```
\includeonly{myreport-tableofcontents}
\input{myreport}
```

### With `hyperref` and links

If `myreport.tex` loads package `hyperref`, then the table of contents file `myreport.toc` also contains anchor names. That can be used to make inter document links. For example,
the overview file for my bundle on CTAN, [oberdiek.pdf](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/oberdiek.pdf) includes the table of contents of all the packages in the bundle. The source file [oberdiek.tex](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/oberdiek.tex) uses
this technique, see the definition of `\tocinclude` in the example below. Of course both `myreport.tex` and `myreport-toc.tex` need `hyperref`.

Also needed:

- Any macros used in `myreport.toc` should be provided in `myreport-toc.tex`.
- The same class, fonts, page layout, … should be used.
- In case of the page number, the example uses `zref` to put the data for the page numbers in the `.aux` file of `myreport`. The label `toc` writes the page number for the start page of the table of contents. By using module `zref-thepage` also the visual appearance of all page numbers in the document are remembered. The `.aux` file of `myreport` is then read by `zref-xr` in `myreport-toc.tex`.

File `myreport.tex`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{zref-abspage,zref-thepage}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\pagevaluelabel}[1]{%
  \zref@labelbyprops{toc}{abspage}%
}
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\providecommand\string\pagevaluelabel[1]{}}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\pagevaluelabel{toc}}%
}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

Title page
\newpage

\chapter*{Foreword}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

File `myreport-toc.tex`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{zref-xr}
\zexternaldocument[main:]{test}\relax

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\tocinclude}[1]{%
  \chapter*{\contentsname
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
            {\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
  }%
  \begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \def\@prj{#1}%
    \let\contentsline\foreign@contentsline
    \input{\@prj.toc}%
  \endgroup
}
\def\foreign@contentsline#1#2#3#4{%
  \ifx\\#4\\%
    \csname l@#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
  \else
    \ifHy@linktocpage
      \csname l@#1\endcsname{{#2}}{%
        \hyper@linkfile{#3}{\@prj.pdf}{#4}%
      }%
    \else
      \csname l@#1\endcsname{%
        \hyper@linkfile{#2}{\@prj.pdf}{#4}%
      }{#3}%
    \fi
  \fi
}%

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\zref@refused{main:toc}
\setcounter{page}{%
  \numexpr\zref@extractdefault{main:toc}{abspage}{1}\relax
}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{%
  \zref@extractdefault{main:thepage\number\value{page}}%
  {page}{\arabic{page}}%
}
\tocinclude{myreport}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

### First method (with [`shorttoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/shorttoc))

The easiest method is to use the command `\anothertableofcontents` from the `shorttoc` package, which loads and prints the ToC from an arbitrary `.toc` file.

If your main document is

**`my-report.tex`**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}    
\tableofcontents    
\blinddocument    
\end{document}
```

create a `my-report-toc.tex` with the following contents

**`my-report-toc.tex`**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{xspace}  % this shouldn't be needed in your document

\begin{document}
\anothertableofcontents{my-report}{Contents}{3}
\end{document}
```

Compiling the latter, the resulting `my-report-toc.pdf` will contain the ToC of `my-report.pdf`:

[image]

---

### Second method (with [`pdfpages`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages))

Another method is to use the `pdfpages` package to load only the pages of the ToC in a different file. In this case, the pages containing the ToC must not contain anything else.

If your main document is

**`my-report.tex`**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}    
\tableofcontents 
\clearpage   
\blinddocument    
\end{document}
```

create a `my-report-toc.tex` with the following contents (replace `pages=1` with the real range of pages of your ToC)

**`my-report-toc.tex`**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1]{my-report.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Compiling the latter, the resulting `my-report-toc.pdf` will contain the ToC of `my-report.pdf`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pdfseparate` to extract a page, or range of pages, from a pdf file.

Assuming the table of contents is only one page long, try `pdfseparate -f 2 -l 2 my-report.pdf my-report-toc.pdf`

Of course, this requires that you know how many pages the table of contents takes up.

Comment: There are several ways to extract pages from a pdf. See the answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54157/compiling-master-and-individual-child-documents-with-correct-pagination/54227#54227

Answer (score 0):

Quick and very dirty hack (far from robust) for the lazy ones:

You have to compile the original document twice, which gives `my-report.tex`. Now modify the document a bit:

**modified document**:

```
\begin{document}
...
\begin{titlepage}
\includepdf[pages=-]{abstract.pdf}
\end{titlepage}

% -------------------------------------------------    
% This should go to a separate .pdf file on export.
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak
% -------------------------------------------------
\end{document} %THIS LINE IS IMPORTANT!
\section{Section1}
...
\section{Section2}
...
\section{Section3}
...
\end{document}
```

And compile it **once**. The table of contents is created, nothing else. This worked for me using `pdflatex` in the commandline or `texmaker`.

**Edit:**
Of course you have to do this again, if you changed your document, therefore if you want to generate tables of content frequently this solution is probably the wrong one.

Comment: This is just deleting the content of your document which is not a robust solution. It's dirty but not quick as you have to do this every time you change the document.

Comment: You are completely right with your remark, but for a quick and _simple_ output of your table of contents (e.g. giving someone the outline of your document for review) its sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

`mycontents.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section*{My Contents}
\input{mwe.toc}
\end{document}
```

Where `mwe.toc` is the auxiliary file of your *already compiled* `mwe.tex` main document in the same directory.

Take care that some editors can move these files to another place or  remove the auxiliary files after compiling, but there are not problems compiling from a terminal.