# Chapters or sections in different files

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keep chapter number of chapters inserted with \include](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3462/keep-chapter-number-of-chapters-inserted-with-include)

I would like to write down a paper with 4 chapters or sections and I would like to write them in separate files and then compile all of them together (the references also). How can I do this?

Comment: See this one : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3462/keep-chapter-number-of-chapters-inserted-with-include

Comment: If you want to be able to compile each chapter by itelse as you write them, you should also have a look at [the `standalone` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone) -- There are numerous answers  on this site showing examples.