# ignoring chapter easily

Tags: macros, sectioning

When working on a book I'd like to "ignore"(not compile) all chapters but the current one. I know there are methods to use like include and such BUT I do not want to use external files or some complex method.

I simply want to use `\iffalse` and `fi`(or something similar) BUT I want it transparent:

e.g.,

```
\ignorechapters{3,4} % <- Ignores all chapters **BUT** 3,4
```

and that is all that is needed so that only chapters 3 and 4 show up in the pdf.

So what is needed to do this? I imagine each `\chapter` macro will need to be modified in a robust way so that it will conditionally include the chapter or not

e.g., normally one has

```
\chapter[mc]{my chapter}
....
\chapter[mc2]{my chapter 2}
....
\chapter[mc3]{my chapter 3}
```

and I do this manually:

```
\chapter[mc]{my chapter}
\iffalse
....
\fi
\chapter[mc2]{my chapter 2}
\iffalse
....
\fi
\chapter[mc3]{my chapter 3}
```

and as you can see, it each `\iffalse` and `\fi` could easily be consumed into the `\chapter` macro without causing problems and done so transparently. (Assuming we can modify `\chapter` easily and not break it's original functionality)

--- Edit pseudo-code

```
newchapter macro
if previous chapter ignored  % Obviously if previous chapter doesn't exist this should be ignored
   insert `\fi`
end
if chapter ignored
   insert `\iffalse`
end
   insert `chapter data`
end macro
```

Hence the the newchapter macro will insert a `\fi` then an `\iffalse` into the stream if necessary.

We would also have to override the `\end{document}` to insert the final `\fi` if necessary(if the last chapter is to be ignored(which means it has an `\iffalse` and requires a `\fi`).

Comment: Why don't you want to use `\include` for your chapters?

Comment: and then `\includeonly` [keep-chapter-number-of-chapters-inserted-with-include](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3462/keep-chapter-number-of-chapters-inserted-with-include)

Comment: Where does `\ignorechapters` get you that `\includeonly`|`include` get you besides the fact that the 'ignored' chapters are the ones that get included?

Comment: Are you concerned about inter-chapter references, since `\iffalse`...`\fi` would just ignore them and might cause undefined references?

Comment: Why does everyone try to rewrite my question into asking about something else instead of just giving me a solution? As I said, I'm not interested in using `\include` and it's my business as to why I do not want to use external files... and that should be good enough!

Comment: @Werner: I do not care about that but about speeding up compile time...

Comment: @jon um, one requires using external files and one doesn't... HUGE difference in my book... and that's what count's.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following example implements the syntax described in the question. I have renamed `\ignorechapters` to `\includechapters`, because the chapters in the argument should be included, not ignored. Also I follow the convention of `\includeonly`: If `\includechapters` is not specified, all chapters are included. Otherwise the chapters are included that are specified. Starred chapters and chapters that are not followed by \iffalse are always included.

The normal syntax for `\chapter` is supported:

- `\chapter*{...}`
- `\chapter{...}`
- `\chapter[...]{...}`

Excluded chapters

- call `\cleardoublepage`,
- increment their chapter number and
- write an entry into the table of contents.

Package `ltxcmds` is only needed for a more robust `\ltx@ifnextchar` that also allows a conditional as next token.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\includechapters}[1]{%
  \def\@includechapters{#1}%
}
\let\@includechapters\relax
\newcommand*{\org@chapter}{}
\let\org@chapter\chapter
\renewcommand*{\chapter}{%
  \@ifstar{\org@chapter*}{\chapter@aux}%
}
\newcommand*{\chapter@aux}{%
  \begingroup
  \@ifnextchar[{\chapter@aux@opt}{%
    \toks@{\org@chapter}%
    \let\chapter@tocentry\relax
    \chapter@@aux
  }%
}
\def\chapter@aux@opt[#1]{%
  \toks@{\org@chapter[{#1}]}%
  \def\chapter@tocentry{#1}%
  \chapter@@aux
}
\newcommand*{\chapter@@aux}[1]{%
  \toks@\expandafter{\the\toks@{#1}}%
  \ifx\chapter@tocentry\relax
    \def\chapter@tocentry{#1}%
  \fi
  \ltx@ifnextchar\iffalse{%
    \chapter@select
  }{%
    \expandafter\endgroup
    \the\toks@
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\chapter@select}[1]{%
  \ifx\@includechapters\relax
    \def\x{true}%
  \else
    \def\x{false}%
    \@for\ch:=\@includechapters\do{%
      \ifnum\ch=\numexpr\value{chapter}+1\relax
        \def\x{true}%
      \fi
    }%
  \fi
  \csname if\x\endcsname
  \else
    \cleardoublepage
    \refstepcounter{chapter}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{%
      \protect\numberline{\thechapter}%
      \chapter@tocentry
    }%
  \fi
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \csname if\x\expandafter\endcsname
  \the\toks@
}

\makeatother

\includechapters{2}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter[mc]{my chapter}
\iffalse
....
\fi
\chapter[mc2]{my chapter 2}
\iffalse 
....  
\fi  
\chapter[mc3]{my chapter 3}

\end{document}
```

The example includes the table of contents (starred chapter), excludes "my chapter", includes "my chapter 2", because it is listed in `\includechapters`, and includes "my chapter 3", because it is not followed by `\iffalse`.

**Update:**
The method with `\iffalse` will not work, if the markup should be hidden inside `\chapter` without explicit markup for the end of chapter. When `\iffalse` is active, then TeX's fast scanning looks for conditional tokens only to find the matching `\fi`. Therefore a command token with the meaning of `\fi` that is not hidden inside macros is needed at any case.

### Method via discarding pages

The following methods uses the property of chapters that they start and end at page breaks.
If a chapter is ignored, then the chapter is typeset as usual, but the pages are discarded.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{atbegshi}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\includechapters}[1]{%
  \def\@includechapters{#1}%
}
\let\@includechapters\relax
\newcommand*{\org@chapter}{}
\newif\if@ignore@chapter
\renewcommand*{\@ignore@chaptertrue}{\global\let\if@ignore@chapter\iftrue}
\renewcommand*{\@ignore@chapterfalse}{\global\let\if@ignore@chapter\iffalse}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \if@ignore@chapter
    \AtBeginShipoutDiscard
  \fi
}
\let\org@chapter\chapter
\renewcommand*{\chapter}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \@ignore@chapterfalse
  \@ifstar{\org@chapter*}{\chapter@aux}%
}
\newcommand*{\chapter@aux}{%
  \begingroup
  \@ifnextchar[{\chapter@aux@opt}{%
    \toks@{\org@chapter}%
    \let\chapter@tocentry\relax
    \chapter@@aux
  }%
}
\def\chapter@aux@opt[#1]{%
  \toks@{\org@chapter[{#1}]}%
  \def\chapter@tocentry{#1}%
  \chapter@@aux
}
\newcommand*{\chapter@@aux}[1]{%
  \toks@\expandafter{\the\toks@{#1}}%
  \ifx\chapter@tocentry\relax
    \def\chapter@tocentry{#1}%
  \fi
  \ifx\@includechapters\relax
    \@ignore@chapterfalse
  \else
    \@ignore@chaptertrue
    \@for\ch:=\@includechapters\do{%
      \ifnum\ch=\numexpr\value{chapter}+1\relax
        \@ignore@chapterfalse
      \fi
    }%
  \fi
  \expandafter\endgroup\the\toks@
}
\makeatother

\includechapters{2}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter[mc]{my chapter}
....\the\currentgrouplevel
\chapter[mc2]{my chapter 2}
....
\chapter[mc3]{my chapter 3}

\end{document}
```

Now only the pages of the table of contents and chapter "my chapter 2" are included.

Comment: I think this is on the right track but you misinterpreted my question slightly. I do not want to have to explicitly use `\iffalse` and `\fi`. I want it to be automatically inserted. What you have will work so I have marked it as correct but please try and fix it.

Comment: your example should look like `\chapter[mc]{my chapter} .... \chapter[mc2]{my chapter 2} .... \chapter[mc3]{my chapter 3}` at the bottom.

Comment: (Note that the behavior you have of your example is correct but instead of inserting the `\iffalse` and `\fi`'s you delete them)

Comment: That's not possible. The `\fi` must be visible somehow, otherwise all would be ignored including `\end{document}` if a chapter is skipped. Even with the `comment` package you need a markup for the end of chapter that cannot be hidden inside macros.

Comment: huh? It definitely is possible. Your macro must be logical enough to realize it is the last chapter! (the same type of logic must prevent a `\fi` from the first chapter. I'll ammend my questio with some pseudo code.

Comment: Essentially all it boils down to is checking if a chapter number is in the included chapters list and if it isn't we surround everything in the the chapter with a `\iffalse` and `\fi`(exactly how one would do it manually). (one doesn't even need to do this... possibly just ignoring the chapter has the same effect).

Comment: No. If `\iffalse` is active, then it needs a command token with the meaning of `\fi` that cannot be hidden inside macros. And the last chapter is known at the very end of document.

Comment: There is a `\fi` macro trick, do you know about it?

Comment: If using `\iffalse` and `\fi` are complicated you can chose just to ignore all the chapter tokens. There is no real reason to use `\iffalse` and `\fi` if using macros. I used them because it is required, or some variant, when having to do it by hand.

Comment: See the edited answer for a different method via discarding pages.

Comment: That looks like it does the job! I really appreciate it. It makes it very easy to remove chapters if necessary.

Comment: and I was also able to plug in play into my project without having modify anything but insert the `\includeonly` macro! Just what I wanted!

Answer (score 3):

You could load the `comment` package and surround the temporarily unwanted chapters with `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}` instructions. Note that these instructions must be on lines by themselves, with no leading blank (space) characters preceding them on the line.

Comment: You can also add various names for comments, e.g. `\includecomment{chapter1}` and surround the first chapter by `\begin{chapter1}` and `\end{chapter1}`. (You can find more details in the comment package documentation.)