# Compiling multiple tex files into a single file

Tags: errors

I was writing my masters' thesis using Latex and have written 4 chapters in 4 different `.tex` files. Now I wish to combine all these chapters into a single `.pdf` file. For this I wrote a main `.tex` file in which I included the 4 tex files using `\include` statement. However, everytime I run the main tex file, I see an error message :

> Message : ! Latex error ! Can be used only in preamble.

What I wrote in the main tex file was the following :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{thesis}
%\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{varioref}                                                               %   when using \vref the page the figure is on is printed
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}                          %   enables caption adjustments
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{url}                                                                    %   makes nice url's
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm,right=3cm,top=4cm,bottom=4cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{mathcomp}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{bbm}                                                                    %   enables \mathbbm
\usepackage{lscape}                                                                 %   enables landscape tables
%\usepackage{lettrine}                                                               %   enables dropcaps ('miniaturen')
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}

%\usepackage{here}
%\usepackage{rotate}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{picins}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{cite} 

\begin{document}
\include{Chapter1_Introduction_Final}       % Names of my tex files           
\include{Chapter2_STIOS}                   
\include{Chapter3_FrequencyStabilization}                  
\include{Chapter4_VHDLperformance}                  
\end{document}
```

If I compile each `.tex` file individually , then I get separate `.pdf` files. However, I want to generate a single `.pdf` file consisting of all 4 chapters. I would be obliged for the assistance.

Comment: There are packages that try to automate including separate documents but the simplest thing to do is do as you have done and use the standard `\include`  and then remove the preamble and `document` environment of each of the chapters.

Comment: Exactly the same as @DavidCarlisle: Make sure your chapters only start by `\chapter{Chaptertitle}` and only include the text itself.  At this point of `inclusion` they should not be standalone, i.e., they should only require your preamble of your main file

Comment: see [How to best use and compile multiple .tex files as part of same final document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94414/579)

Comment: For one possible strategy see my answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123058/subimport-and-includeonly/123096#123096

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have a separate preamble in each of your sub files. Latex can only handle one preamble in the master document. You could now either delete/comment the preamble in the chapter-files, or you can use the combination of the `standalone` package-class combination.

In your chapter files you can use the documentclass `\documentclass{standalone}` and in your master file you load the `\usepackage{standalone}`.

This should then remove the preambles from your chapter-files. This way you can still compile the individual files, or you can compile the master document.

Answer (score 1):

To keep your source clean, I would recommend to only have the preamble in the master document, but compile a part of your document by means of `\includeonly{}` or `\excludeonly{}`. For `\excludeonly`, you need to load the underlying package by `\usepackage{excludeonly}`.
The advantage of this approach is that the chapter and page numbers will be like in the complete document, whereas compiling single chapters fully standalone will result in multiple chapters 1.