# Compiling only a page range or page selection

Tags: compiling

How do I easily compile only a page range or page selection? That is, I would like a document that

- looks exactly like the full document,
- **has only the subset of pages that were manually chosen, by page number** (this can be one contiguous range or a more complicated selection, like "12-15,23,45-49"),
- has correct page numbers, and
- has correct links, except links to missing pages should be either dysfunctional or absent.

Comment: So `\input`, `\includeonly` type of solutions are not allowed right? I mean like this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3462/keep-chapter-number-of-chapters-inserted-with-include

Comment: @percuße I would say they are not allowed because I would really like to specify *page* ranges. In any case, thanks for linking to this!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[`atbegshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi) provides the capability to discard a ready-to-be-shipped-out page using `\AtBeginShipoutDiscard`. Together with [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s list-processing capability, you can easily discard/retain pages conditionally:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,atbegshi,etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lipsum,atbegshi,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\discardpages}[1]{% \discardpages{<csv list>}
  \xdef\discard@pages{#1}% Store pages to discard
  \AtBeginShipout{% At shipout, decide whether to discard page/not
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{% How to handle each page entry in csv list
      \ifnum\value{page}=##1\relax%
        \AtBeginShipoutDiscard% Discard page/not
        \gdef\do####1{}% Do nothing further
      \fi%
    }%
    \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\discard@pages}% Process list of pages to discard
  }%
}
\newif\ifkeeppage
\newcommand{\keeppages}[1]{% \keeppages{<csv list>}
  \xdef\keep@pages{#1}% Store pages to keep
  \AtBeginShipout{% At shipout, decide whether to discard page/not
    \keeppagefalse%
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{% How to handle each page entry in csv list
      \ifnum\value{page}=##1\relax%
        \keeppagetrue% Page should be kept
        \gdef\do####1{}% Do nothing further
      \fi%
    }%
    \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\keep@pages}% Process list of pages to keep
    \ifkeeppage\else\AtBeginShipoutDiscard\fi% Discard page/not
  }%
}
\makeatother
\discardpages{1,3,5,7,9,29,35,40}% Discard these pages.
%\keeppages{2,4,6}% Keep these pages.
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

The above 47-page document is scaled down to 39 after having removed the 8 pages 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 29, 35, 40 (as supplied by `\discardpages{1,3,5,7,9,29,35,40}`). To discard zero pages, you could use `\discardpages{}` (or make no call to `\discardpages`). Using `\keeppages{2,4,6}` instead leaves you with a 3-page document consisting of only pages 2, 4 and 6. It should not be that difficult to extend this to include more complicated page ranges.

The above has *not* been tested with hyperlinks from [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).

Comment: Presumably though for pages that are not shipped out won't write references etc so you'd need to do a full run first then do this with `\nofiles` to keep the original cross ref info?

Comment: Let me add that `\nofiles` is a command for the preamble, which ensures that auxiliary files are not modified during the current compilation run.

Comment: I just tried, and this seems to work with `hyperref`, though I've tested only links from the TOC.

Comment: Instead of comparing the number of the page `\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\thepage}{##1}=\z@%` will let you insert the page numbers as they are (would be) on the page. This makes it possible to distinct between normal pages and the frontmatter for example

Comment: Is there any way to relabel the page's number once extracted? I have a ToC that appears on every partial document I extracted that way as well as a final page, and then each partial doc is comprised of chapter 1-x of part I and chapter 1-x of part 2.  The page numbering correspond to the original and I would like it to be i,ii,iii,...  , 1,2,...

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien: Technically you can't renumber them. However, you can write a block of white text over the existing page number with a new page number. If that's what you want, consider [asking a new question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), as it's completely different from this one.

Answer (score 48):

In the line of David Carlisle's answer, but using pure latex tools, I'm suprised no one mentioned `pdfpages` package.

You can compile your full document and then extract the required pages using another latex "driving" document whichs uses `pdfpages`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article} % Not really important
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={12-15,23,45-49}]{main.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: 1. This works. 2. This basically disables all links (originally created by `hyperref`).

Comment: Excellent answer! I'll wait though if someone comes up with an answer that will keep all the document-internal links.

Comment: The only known solution for this problem is pax (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pax/), but it is in experimental status (and I never tried it)

Comment: **Or** possibly an adaptation of Werner's answer :-) But you mentioning "Project pax" is a good pointer.

Comment: There is also a command-line interface to pdfpages, called pdfjam. The issue I've encountered is that pdfjam has the side-effect of subsetting all fonts, which I don't want. I think it's possible to work around this, however, using something like pdfjam --preamble '\pdfmapfile{=fullembed.map}' (not tested).

Comment: This method kills hyperlinks.  It seems to be the same thing as using a "print to PDF" on the original document to select pages -- links don't work.

Comment: this is ingenious :-) thank you su much

Comment: Well, this compiles the whole document, I think. I found that question while looking for a way to only *compile* a certain page range with my focus being the faster compilation of a big document.

Answer (score 35):

Also the following packages should be mentioned:

- [selectp](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/selectp): [for plain TeX and LaTeX 2.09]

> Select pages to be out­put
>
> De­fines a com­mand `\out­pu­tonly`, whose ar­gu­ment is a list of pages
>   to be out­put. With the com­mand present (be­fore
>   `\be­gin{doc­u­ment}`), only those pages are out­put.

- [selectpage](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/selectpage):

> Select pages to be out­put from a doc­u­ment
>
> Re­quires a file of page num­bers, which spec­i­fies the num­bers of pages to print (in gen­er­ated or­der).

- [pagesel](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pagesel): [for LaTeX 2]

> Select pages of a doc­u­ment for out­put
>
> Selects sin­gle pages, ranges of pages, odd pages or even pages for
>   out­put. The pack­age is part of the oberdiek bun­dle.

(http://www.ctan.org/topic/page-control).

Comment: Something as simple as `\usepackage[26-30]{pagesel}` seems to do it!

Comment: Thanks! And: You would not  expect otherwise of a "pack­age [...] of the Oberdiek bun­dle", would you? :-)

Comment: This is excellent.  Unlike pdfpages, this perserves hyperlinks.  Thanks.

Comment: Here is the easiest solution to render from page 1 to page 10. `\usepackage[1-10]{pagesel}`

Answer (score 20):

You can latex the full document and post process with a pdf tool there are several eg this one is on my system

```
NAME
       pdfseparate - Portable Document Format (PDF) page extractor

SYNOPSIS
       pdfseparate [options] PDF-file PDF-page-pattern

DESCRIPTION
       pdfseparate extract single pages from a Portable Document Format (PDF).

       pdfseparate  reads  the  PDF file PDF-file, extracts one or more pages, and writes one PDF file for
       each page to PDF-page-pattern, PDF-page-pattern should contain %d.  %d is replaced by the page number.
```

I was going to add that an alternative would be to get tex to only shipout certain pages but @Werner just posted code for such a solution so I'll just leave this as a post processing alternative (which can be more robust depending on the tex code that is interacting with the shipout changes).

Comment: It so happens I had to do just this a couple of minutes ago, and this is the way I went with. A [Google search](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-extract-pages-pdf) gave me this full command: `pdftk A=inputfile.pdf cat A22-36 output outfile_p22-p36.pdf` and it worked as expected.

Comment: @jja: I would not advise anyone to hitch their wagon to pdftk at this point. It uses its own extremely out of date fork of the iText library, which doesn't seem to be receiving any maintenance or bug fixes. When it gets an error from iText, it throws away all the info iText sends back about what the error is. My experience has been that postprocessing pdftex output through tools like gs and pdftk produces many problems with RIPs, and those problems are extremely hard to diagnose.

Comment: Pdfseparate uses the Poppler library, which seems to be of high quality and well maintained. But it would be a little awkward for this task; if you were going to pull 100 pages out, you'd have to make 100 files using pdfseparate and then concatenate them with pdfunite.

Comment: @BenCrowell: Are you saying that `pdftk` is unreliable *for this task*?  I've had some issues with it for other things (adding/extracting metadata, filling out forms, etc.), but for simple concatenation or page extraction it's worked well for me.

Comment: @Matthew Leingang: Yes, I'm saying both that pdftk is unreliable for that task and that it's poorly engineered and poorly maintained in general. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libitext-java/+bug/1110674

Comment: I can't even find a way to install `pdftk` on my CentOS 7 system.

Answer (score 4):

Here is Werner's solution without the cost of the per-page loops.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,atbegshi}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\discardpages}[1]{%
  \xdef\discard@pages{\zap@space#1 \@empty}%
  \AtBeginShipout{%
    \@expandtwoargs\in@{,\the\c@page,}{,\discard@pages,}%
    \ifin@\AtBeginShipoutDiscard\fi
  }%
}
\newcommand{\keeppages}[1]{%
  \xdef\keep@pages{\zap@space#1 \@empty}%
  \AtBeginShipout{%
    \@expandtwoargs\in@{,\the\c@page,}{,\keep@pages,}%
    \ifin@\else\AtBeginShipoutDiscard\fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

% Examples:
\discardpages{1,3,5,7,9,29,35,40}
%\keeppages{2,4,6}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to discard only the 1st page? I naively tried with `\AtBeginShipout{\ifx\the\c@page1\AtBeginShipoutDiscard\fi}` without success. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak for the OP, but when I do this, I don't really want to use hardcoded page numbers. I want to break up a book into volumes, and `\includeonly` doesn't do what I want because I want a single table of contents and a single index to be included in both volumes. I also want, e.g., to be able to do a `\pageref` from vol. 2 back to a page number in vol. 1.

The perl script below is what I use for this purpose. It invokes pdftk to filter the pdf file that was output by pdflatex. Because pdftk is buggy and poorly maintained, I would actually suggest that others do this kind of thing using pdfjam or poppler utils instead.

There is a configuration file that looks like this:

```
1,2,,3,ch:intro,-1,
1,1,ch:intro,0,splits:startvol2,-3,
2,2,splits:startvol2,-2,splits:index,-1,
1,2,splits:index,0,splits:data,-1,
1,2,splits:data,0,end,,5
```

The first line, for example, says that both volume 1 and volume 2 should start at page 3 and continue until one page before the first chapter. `ch:intro` is the latex label for the first chapter.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $input_file = $ARGV[0];
my $vol = $ARGV[1];
my $output_file = $ARGV[2];


# reads save.ref and splits.config
#
# format of splits.config:
#    v1,v2,label1,offset1,label2,offset2,mod8
#    (v1,v2)=(1,1) means only include these pages in volume 1
#    (v1,v2)=(2,2) means only include these pages in volume 2
#    (v1,v2)=(1,2) means include these pages in both volumes
#    label1=latex label of beginning of range, or null
#    offset1=offset from label1; if label1 is null string and offset is +, then take offset1 as page number; if label1 is 'end' and offset is '', take last page
#    label2,offset2=similar for end of range
#    mod8=if not null, force it to start on a page of the output pdf that equals this, modulo 8
#      You typically want the output pdf to have a number of pages that is a multiple of 8. So, e.g., if LM has three pages of data, etc., at the end,
#      set mod8 to 5, so that the third page will equal 7 mod 8.

my %refs = ();
open(F,"<save.ref") or die "error opening save.ref for input";
while (my $line = <F>) {
  chomp $line;
  if ($line =~ /([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)/) {
    my ($label,$name,$page) = ($1,$2,$3);
    $refs{$label} = $page;
  }
}
close(F);

open(F,"<splits.config") or die "error opening splits.config for input";
my @pages = ();
my $n = 0;
while (my $line = <F>) {
  chomp $line;
  if ($line =~ /([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)/) {
    my ($v1,$v2,$l1,$o1,$l2,$o2,$m) = ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7);
    #print "$v1,$v2,$l1,$o1,$l2,$o2,$m\n";
    my $p1 = find_page($l1,$o1);
    my $p2 = find_page($l2,$o2);
    #print "pages $p1-$p2\n";
    my $chunk = 0;
    if ($vol>=$v1 && $vol<=$v2) {
      if ($p1%2 != 1) {push @pages,"B1"; ++$chunk}
      if ($m ne '') {
        while (($n+$chunk)%8!=$m) {push @pages,"B1"; ++$chunk}
      }
      push @pages,"$p1-$p2";
      if ($p2 ne 'end') {
        $chunk += (($p2-$p1)+1);
        if ($chunk%2!=0) {push @pages,"B1"; ++$chunk}
      }
      print "input $p1-$p2 -> output ",($n+1),"-",($p2 eq 'end' ? 'end' : $n+$chunk),"\n";
      $n += $chunk;
    }
  }
}
close(F);

my $c = "pdftk $input_file B=../share/misc/blank_page.pdf  cat ".join(' ',@pages)." output $output_file";
print "$c\n";
system $c;

sub find_page {
  my $l = shift;
  my $o = shift;
  if ($l eq '') {return $o}
  if ($l eq 'end') {return 'end'}
  if (!exists $refs{$l}) {die "label $l doesn't exist in save.ref"}
  return $refs{$l}+$o;
}

sub barf {
  my $message = shift;
  print STDERR "splits.pl: $message\n";
  print STDERR "You will need to edit splits.config.\n";
  exit(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Lover of Structure's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96256/compiling-only-a-page-range-or-page-selection/698094#comment219123_100475) as an answer:

```tex
\usepackage[26-30]{pagesel}
```

Include this before `begin{document}`. No other commands or extra files needed.

If you get a "temporary page" after the final page that won't go away, add a few `\newpage` and `\clearpage` commands followed by some random text just before `\end{document}` to add some extra pages, which Latex can then for some reason figure out how to trim off.