# Beamer theorem numbering issue

Tags: beamer, numbering

I have a `beamer` presentation containing slides for multiple lectures in a single file. Exercises in the slides should be number continuously from the first lecture to the last. So lecture 1 ends with exercise 10, lecture 2 starts with exercise  11 and so on.

When I use `\includeonlyframes` to make a presentation for a particular lecture it always starts numbering from one again. So, lecture 2 starts again from 1, rather then 11 I would like to see.

It appears that `\includeonlyframes` doesn't read frames that are not included at all. 
Is there a way to make it read all frames and output the right ones, but preserve the numbering in the process?

Comment: You can compile the whole document then extract the frames for your particular lecture via `pdftk`...

Comment: Consider some of the solutions suggested in [Compiling only a page range or page selection](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96256/5764).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. That's what I am doing right now, but I am wondering if there is a way of doing it from inside latex

Comment: @user26977: You can select *pages* (not frames) using `\usepackage[<page range>]{pagesel}`.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `\includeonlyframes` isn't designed to read all the frames. From the [Beamer User Guide](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), Section 4.3.3 (Ways of Improving Compilation Speed):

> This command behaves **a little bit** like the `\includeonly` command: Only the frames mentioned in the list are included.

(emphasis mine). Only the section and subsection commands are still executed, for getting correct navigation bars. Since `\includeonlyframes` is a way to improve the compilation speed, it *shouldn't* read the contents of the frames. Of course it would be nice to have a version that does it nonetheless ...

I see only one simple way out of your problem: add something like `\setcounter{exercise}{10}` before your frames for lecture 2, where `10` should be the last exercise from lecture 1. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\includeonlyframes{t2}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=t1]
\begin{theorem}
First theorem
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\setcounter{theorem}{1}
\begin{frame}[label=t2]
\begin{theorem}
Second theorem
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

By the way, it would be good if you include an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) in your next question; it took me some time to write the above code since I didn't know about `\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]` before.