# Compiling small part of text

Tags: compiling, winedt

I'm using winedt for Latex. sometimes I'm only working on a section of my paper and want to recompile to PDF without going through the whole time-consuming compilation. Is there a way I can tell Latex I've just changed a part of the text (or a section) so that it goes faster.

I know about `\includeonly` but this seems to work on specific chapters rather than at a micro level like my problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: See also LaTeX-only and not WinEdt-specific http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96256/compiling-only-a-page-range-or-page-selection

Answer (score 14):

WinEdt has a very interesting feature for that.

Simply select the section you want, and press the button "Compile Selected" in the toolbar or press <kbd>Shift+F9</kbd>.

[image]

WinEdt will use your preamble to determine your settings and create a new hidden document that is compiled, so you can see the output of the selected text, without compiling the whole document.

Comment: @user72270 You're welcome. Remember that you can accept (and upvote) the answer to mark the question as solved. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Comment: Great feature! Nice to know about it.

Answer (score 2):

I have made a [live preview plugin](http://zohooo.github.io/quadview) for WinEdt. It will show the preview of current paragraph in the upper right corner of WinEdt. Furthermore it will update the preview automatically if current paragraph has been changed.

[image]