# Selectively compiling source in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, compiling, sublime-text, performance

I have recently switched from Xe(La)TeX to Lua(La)TeX 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017) in order to use font expansion feature of `microtype` package.

As a result, my compilation time increased dramatically. I confirmed that performance decrease is caused by LuaLaTeX itself, as removing `microtype` package doesn't speed the process.

For medium-size document (about 300 pages) I went from 1.9s compilation time with XeLaTeX to 4.2s seconds with LuaLaTeX.

It wouldn't it too bad if I run it only a handful of times, but I am doing manual adjustments to page breaking and hence I need to run it very frequently.

If I run LuaLaTeX only on 1 chapter (10 pages or so), I get PDF in 1.4s.

Is there any way to tell LuaLaTeX to only generate few pages around last edit point, or only a chapter in which edit took place? Ideally, it would preserve earlier part of the PDF file, so that pages do not move in PDF viewer, but anything after currently edited chapter can be ignored.

Additional information based on comments:

- I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit.
- In case it matters, I edit my source files in Sublime Text 3.
- I am not using cross-references or any "interactive" elements, which might affect or be affected by pagebreaking. Just plain, literal text.
- For chapter headings I am using `\chapter*` with chapter numbers written manually.

Comment: Please tell us more about the platform that you're running TeXLive2017 on. Is it, by any chance, a MacOS system?

Comment: It is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit. Side note: I assume doing what I need might require using diff somehow to detect last edit point, but I do not know if this wouldn't slow down things even more.

Comment: Unfortunately you're not on Windows, otherwise WinEdt has a very useful feature for that which I use very often... See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227909/80972

Comment: @Arzigoglu Very interesting. Though, I am kind of addicted to Sublime Text, so probably would not use WinEdt anyway ;)

Comment: How exact has the partly compilation to be? If you are fine tuning the page breaking then almost every other part of the document can influence it, e.g. through references, citation, acronyms, etc.

Comment: The `luatex` executable is slow, I have noticed that as well. I use `pdftex` whenever possible, which is both fast and compatible with `microtype`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This is basic text without cross references, citation, acronyms and other things that do change with different page breaking. Also, preamble doesn't change during these partly compilations.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer I need ability to use OpenType fonts easily, which is only possible with Lua(La)TeX and Xe(La)TeX. I was using the latter for few years until very recently, but with stable version of Lua(La)TeX that comes with TeX Live 2017, I made the switch in order to use ``microtype`` font expansion.

Comment: Then I would use \include and \includeonly to work on one chapter, or simply comment out the \input  commands for the other chapters.

Comment: I realize it's a bit involved, but `otftotfm` can be used to get OTF fonts into `pdflatex`. If you just use one or a few fonts repeatedly, it may be worth it. See for example https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb27-2/tb87owens.pdf

Comment: 1. If you have a feature request please create an issue at [github](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues) 2. You may also have a look at the [subfiles package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfiles), which sounds like it solves your problem (if you use that you should enable [prereleases](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools#prereleases), because special support for that package has been added there)