# TikZ & WinEDT project: compile test file

Tags: winedt, workflow

when working on a WinEDT project with many files and a main file, how can I compile another file without closing the project altogether?

Imagine I want to create a TikZ figure, which involves many compilation iterations, and because i don't want the whole document compiled each time i moved the TikZ figure to a new .tex file.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the "Compile Selected" command in WinEdt. Simply select the code from `\begin{tikzpicture}` to `\end{tikzpicture}` and use that command. See for example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/227910

Comment: Happy about that! Happy TeXing!