# How can I preserve hyperlinks in a PDF that is a subset of the pages in a larger PDF?

Tags: hyperref, pdf, links

I would like to send my colleague just part of a document. The document includes hyperlinks from the `hyperref` package for clickable cross-referencing within my document.

I have tried to create a PDF that is a subset of the pages in the larger PDF file by using the "print to file" feature in evince. It works to create a PDF with just some of the pages, but it does not preserve the hyperlinks from `hyperref`. How can I create a PDF with just a subset of the pages from the original PDF yet preserve the hyperlinks?

UPDATE: related: [Compiling only a page range or page selection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96256/compiling-only-a-page-range-or-page-selection).

UPDATE 2: Though Adam Liter's solution works for me, for a (preferable) solution within LaTex see Heiko Oberdiek' answer [below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230738/66983).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer So where/how to ask?

Comment: Not sure if it works, but you might try the command line tool [`pdftk`](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/) for splicing up the PDF. It might preserve the hyperlinks.

Comment: @AdamLiter Although I am used to using `pdftk`, for some reason I thought the solution would be more difficult. `pdftk` **works**, you might want to post it as answer that I would accept? :-)

Comment: I'll post it as an answer so it's more obvious to anyone else who sees this question, but I agree that it should probably ultimately be closed since it's not really a (La)TeX question.

Comment: The question is, how to generate a part of a LaTeX document while preserving links (of course except links, which point outside the selected part of the document). Thus the question is very *on-topic*. Even pure LaTeX solutions exist, see the `\include` feature or package `pagesel`. Therefore the question should be reopened.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek That's a good point. Despite what I said before, I'll also vote to reopen the question. But if it is reopened, then I think it should be reworded. Or, minimally, the title should be changed to something like "How to preserve hyperlinks in PDF when creating PDF with a subset of pages in original PDF". Or something like that. The way that the title and the question itself are worded suggest that the problem is with evince, which makes it seem off-topic.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The `evince` stuff is only a failed try to find a solution. The question is clearly not about doing it in `evince`. And since the base is a LaTeX document and even solutions in LaTeX exist, this is very on-topic.

Comment: wondering: I've taken the liberty of editing your question to make it more on topic for the site now that it has been reopened. If you don't like my changes, please feel free to rollback the edit, but I think the community would appreciate it if the question were worded differently from how you originally posted it now that it has been reopened. So if you do rollback the edit, could you please also reword it using your own words? @HeikoOberdiek: you should go ahead and provide an alternative answer now! `:)`

Comment: @AdamLiter I am happy with the result, thanks! :-)

Comment: @AdamLiter Answer is added.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No problem for me, the question is now reopened and the question is even improved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a non-TeX solution: you can use the command line tool [`pdftk`](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/) to splice up the original PDF and make a new PDF with just a subset of the pages from the original PDF. This will preserve the hyperlinks from the original PDF.

Comment: As I said in the comment, this solution works perfectly well. +1

Comment: HOW? I am struggling with this

Comment: @ChenStatsYu There's an example given in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17776583/2571049).

Comment: @AdamLiter sorry I might have misread the question/answer. I have no problem in preserving the link on original pages. I was looking for a way to preserve them on 2-up pages, putting two A4 side by side and preserve the links.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu Oh, I see. I'm not sure that I know how to do that offhand. But yes, it seems like a separate question—although related—question.

Comment: Can confirm `pdftk` works, whereas `pdfjam` does not.

Answer (score 5):

Also LaTeX solutions are available.

### `\include`, `\includeonly`

The document can be divided at page boundaries into single files, e.g. chapters.
These are then included via `\include`. Then `\includeonly` with the file names, which should be included. Example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\includeonly{Summary}

\begin{document}
  \include{Introduction}
  \include{Theory}
  \include{Experiments}
  \include{Results}
  \include{Summary}
\end{document}
```

### Package `pagesel`

Package `pagesel` can be used, if certain pages should be selected, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[1,11]{pagesel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{Introduction}
  \chapter{Theory}
  \chapter{Experiments}
  \chapter{Results}
  \chapter{Summary}
\end{document}
```

The document is compiled first without package `pagesel` to get correct/updated auxiliary files. With `pagesel`, the auxiliary files are not written by default, but used and the selected pages are output.

### Links pointing outside the selected range

`hyperref` does not know, which pages are excluded, when it generates the links. Depending on the driver, these stale links may be replaced by a link to the beginning of the document, if the links are pointing outside the included range of pages.

Comment: Thank you! Package `pagesel` works, though I have some problem with page numbering, it is somehow shifted (and it is not a shift due to Roman numeral numbering in the beginning; I think the problem is in the style I am using, the output pdf has `Package atbegshi Warning: Ignoring void shipout box` on the top of the first page). 

`\include`, `\includeonly` do not work for me, because I want to get rid also of the introductory pages like titlepage, table of contents and much other stuff which (I think) cannot be done using `\include`.

Comment: Btw. Jeff mentioned [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include) that " `include` doesn't seem to recognize `\label`'s in the included file" whereas `\input` does". Is that true? Because if not, this Jeff's statement should be changed because it only confuses - for me the `\label`'s seem to work.  Also, I linked [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96256/compiling-only-a-page-range-or-page-selection) related question to my question.

Comment: @wondering You can also put the introductory pages into an included file, e.g. (`frontmatter.tex`).

Comment: @wondering `\label` works with `\include`, the data are written in `.aux` files, which are also read, if the file is not included.

Comment: Well, true with the `frontmatter.tex`. In any case, I added a link to your answer in my updated question.