# Ship only the last physical page (or the last two/three physical pages)

Tags: compiling, lastpage, atbegshi

My question is related to and in continuation to
[Compiling only a page range or page selection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96256/compiling-only-a-page-range-or-page-selection)

I would like to output only the last page (or last two/three pages) without knowing the total number of pages in advance. As in the above referred question, compilation should happen for the entire document with all the counters, page number on footers intact.

Is it possible to say something like `\keeppages{-1}` (from the accepted answer to the above question - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96258/26682) and that should do for the last page? I toyed with `pageslts` package but I dont see any way to achieve what I want.

Any ideas?

PS: the question is self explanatory ... a MWE is not really needed here.

Comment: I have a solution that provides the means to use `\keeppages{-3,-1}` to keep only the third-to-last and final page (say), but any references to content on the discarded pages will be lost. Is this a sufficient solution?

Comment: @Werner sure that is acceptable. in fact, the original question and solution also have the same conditions

Comment: @Werner could you please post your solution of enabling ``\keeppages{-3,-1}``?

Comment: Sorry, [done](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411202/5764).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modification to [Compiling only a page range or page selection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96258/5764) that allows you to use negative numbers that counts from the last page. So, for example, you could use

```
\discardpages{-2,-1}
```

to remove the last two pages, or

```
\keeppages{-3,-1}
```

to only keep the third-to-last and final page. The adaptation relies of [`lastpage`](//ctan.org/pkg/lastpage) to place a `\label{LastPage}` on the last page and use the page number in calculations (thanks to [`refcount`](//ctan.org/pkg/refcount)).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,atbegshi,etoolbox}
\usepackage{lastpage,refcount}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\discardpages}[1]{% \discardpages{<csv list>}
  \xdef\discard@pages{#1}% Store pages to discard
  \AtBeginShipout{% At shipout, decide whether to discard page/not
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{% How to handle each page entry in csv list
      \ifnum##1<0
        \ifnum\value{page}=\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}+##1+1\relax
          \AtBeginShipoutDiscard% Discard page/not
          \gdef\do####1{}% Do nothing further
        \fi
      \else% ##1 >= 0
        \ifnum\value{page}=##1\relax%
          \AtBeginShipoutDiscard% Discard page/not
          \gdef\do####1{}% Do nothing further
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
    \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\discard@pages}% Process list of pages to discard
  }%
}

\newif\ifkeeppage
\newcommand{\keeppages}[1]{% \keeppages{<csv list>}
  \xdef\keep@pages{#1}% Store pages to keep
  \AtBeginShipout{% At shipout, decide whether to discard page/not
    \keeppagefalse%
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{% How to handle each page entry in csv list
      \ifnum##1<0
        \ifnum\value{page}=\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}+##1+1\relax
          \keeppagetrue% Page should be kept
          \gdef\do####1{}% Do nothing further
        \fi
      \else% ##1 >= 0
        \ifnum\value{page}=##1\relax%
          \keeppagetrue% Page should be kept
          \gdef\do####1{}% Do nothing further
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
    \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\keep@pages}% Process list of pages to keep
    \ifkeeppage\else\AtBeginShipoutDiscard\fi% Discard page/not
  }%
}
\makeatother

%\discardpages{-2,-1}
\keeppages{-3,-1}% Keep these pages.

\begin{document}

\sloppy\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

The `LastPage` reference will have to settle in order to be effective. So, you'll have to compile at least twice with every change in this `\label` location (or at the first go).

No further testing was done to see whether [`atveryend`](//ctan.org/pkg/atveryend) might be required.

Comment: ...as in [the previous solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96258/5764), this does not preserve cross-references for pages that are removed.

Comment: perfect! However in my real document, I had reassigned ``LastPage`` counter to one (or more, dynamically determined) lesser and the actual last page (or pages) are ununmbered and unreferenced. I tried setting a new temporary counter to keep track of these extra pages and then do this ``\ifnum\value{page}=\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}+\value{unnumberedpages}+##1+1`` in ``\keeppages``. However ``\value{unnumberedpages}`` seems to only be set at the initialized value of 0. Maybe because ``\keeppages{1,-1}`` is called before ``\begin{document}``. Is there a way out?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this approach is that TeX's model is built sequentially out of "boxes" and "glue." To figure out what's on the 17th page, the TeX system needs to layout the previous 16 pages. The question you linked defines some macros that remove pages *after* pdf generation, but those pages are still generated.

The simplest manual way is to open your generated pdf in a viewer and use the "Print to PDF" option, specifying a page range. If you want to do this in an automated way, that would be more platform-dependent.

Comment: In fact, fully generating the pages and _then_ discarding them is the goal ... so that one doesn't have to go through the rigmarole of post-processing the PDF file with some other software or subject to ``pdfpages`` type hack of recompiling.

Comment: @magguu Ah, I see. Werner's solution is probably the best though. You'd think there would be a package that would solve this kind of thing; it doesn't seem like an uncommon thing to want.

Comment: @WalterMays: You can try [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/CC1G55ch). It uses an alternative method to establish a `LastPage` "reference" (thanks to [`atveryend`](//ctan.org/pkg/atveryend)). You can change all references to `LastPage` to something that suits you better. It's just another option.

Comment: @Werner I presume you were replying to this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411180/ship-only-the-last-physical-page-or-the-last-two-three-physical-pages#comment1027378_411202 .. I followed your excellent suggestion with one change ... I defined a new token called ``EndPage`` to do the shovel work for ``\keeppages``, while ``LastPage`` is left undisturbed. And it does work very well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @magguu: Indeed. Glad you found it.