# copy a section from another .tex file

Tags: cross-referencing, copy-paste

I'll try my best to explain..

I need to make a LaTex document every week for a lab. In it, I have the safety sheet of chemicals. Often, I've already done a chemical in an earlier document.
Now, I just go back to that document and scroll a bunch to find that section and copy-paste it. However, the amount of documents begin to pile up and it takes a lot of time.

In one document there are about 10 chemicals every time. If I save them all in seperate files, I'm giving myself more trouble with the preamble, and then I also have a LOT of files.

Is there any possibility to reference to a section of another document and that it just automatically copies?

Comment: `\input{<file with content I want to reuse>}`?

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include

Comment: there is a package catchfilebetweentags which allows to input parts of a file, I don't know if it still works. But imho creating separate files is easier to handle at the end. Less error prone, and you can find the file faster than remembering some tag ...

Comment: See the answers on these pages:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96256/compiling-only-a-page-range-or-page-selection https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4889/input-only-part-of-a-file