# Only compile first page to pdf

Tags: compiling, shipout, remove

I have a ebook that I also have a paperback cover for. This cover contains the current version which I set in an external file. I have now a revision section which I need to populate the current issue but this makes my compiled PDF have extra pages which I don't need. Is it possible to just export the first page and skip the rest or is my current way of manually delete them the only way?

Comment: It's not possible to set the output pages from the compiler. One option may be to put a `\end{document}` statement somewhere in the middle of your cover file, this causes LaTeX to skip the rest of the document - but maybe this would also skip the data that you need for the first page. If you compile the cover separately and include it with `\includepdf` in your main document then you can set the pages. Otherwise you may have some luck using the [atbegshi](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/atbegshi/atbegshi.pdf) package to discard pages of the output.

Comment: Or compile all the pages and post-process your file automatically using `pdftk` or `qpdf`. But to know which option is the most applicable we would need to see a more concrete description of structure of the document(s), including the relevant LaTeX code, and which parts are supposed to go where.

Comment: Yes I think I will go the pdftk route, too much overhead with other options it seems. Thank you for the input.

Comment: You could also use pdfjam which already comes installed with most TeX distributions if you don't want to install anything additional.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\let\shipoutbak=\shipout
{\catcode`\@=11 \gdef\shipout#1#2{\shipoutbak#1{#2}\aftergroup\@@end}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was simple using the "pagesel" package. Only add this:

```
\usepackage[1]{pagesel}
```

And you will output the cover only.

See this answer: [Compiling only a page range or page selection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96256/compiling-only-a-page-range-or-page-selection)

**EDIT**: this wasn't a solution because not all formatting is parsed and the page looks half baked.